# Как поставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

"Он что(,) нам не верит?" — как тут надо расставлять знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1):

ЧТО здесь частица.

***http://rusgram.narod.ru/2591-2640.html***
*§ 2597. Частицы **что, что же, как** подчеркивают вопросительность, а также вносят оттенок непринужденности: **Что**, у вас каждый день такой? (Гоголь); **Он что** же, по-советски женился? (Фед.); Как, очень устал? **Частица *что*** употребляется для выражения сомнения, предположения: А что у вас там, в Новочеркасске, тоже неспокойно? (Фурм.). Частицы **что же**, как могут употребляться для выражения недоумения, удивления, возмущения: Как, и мечтать не может без спроса? (Гонч.); Тогда что же... отдать землю крестьянам? (Л. Никулин). Их обычная позиция - в начале предложения или после словоформы, начинающей собою предложение: Я, что же, действительно могу идти?; У вас, что же, семья, дети?; в этом последнем случае усиливается оттенок неуверенного предположения.*

Думаю, что предложения типа "***Он что, нам не верит***?"образовались в результате изменения сложных предложений "Он что [делает], [он] нам не верит?" Вот почему ***запятая*** в подобного рода конструкциях остаётся.

Comment: У вас битая ссылка, уберите двоеточие.

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря Вам (вообще-то про себя я Вас называю Маэстро, не обижайтесь) узнала, что такое "битая ссылка".

Comment: >про себя я Вас называю Маэстро, не обижайтесь  

Не стою я того. Совершенно не похож. Можно остаться Бегемотусом? Мне этот ник очень нравится, хотя до него было масса других. Я типичный представитель семейства гиппопотамов. И от свинтуса во мне тоже изрядно. )))

Answer (score 1):

Даю свой ответ только по причине битой ссылки, так-то я в основном согласен с [[@EkaterinaKas](/users/997/ekaterinakashtanova4)](/users/997/ekaterinakashtanova4)...

*§ 1693. К вопросительным частицам относятся частицы а, ли (ль), не ... ли, неужели, никак (прост.), ужели (устар.), разве, что за, что, что ли, как. Все эти частицы совмещают значение вопросительности с более или менее ярко выраженной модальной окрашенностью.
...
   Частицы что, что ли, а, как относятся к разговорной, непринужденной речи. Частица что или открывает собою вопросительное предложение, или следует за вынесенным в начало предложения именем: Что, он опять опаздывает?; Он что, опять опаздывает? ...*

[Русская грамматика](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html)

~~~~

По поводу пунктуации. Частица "что" в подбном контексте (кстати, вообще не уверен, возможен ли другой) грамматически выступает в роли сказуемого, однородного с последующим настоящим сказуемым. Поэтому разделяющая запятая вполне уместна.

Comment: Частица в форме сказуемого - это круто. А не перебор ли? Все-таки частица - служебная часть речи. Может, достаточно сказать, что однородное сказуемое просто опущено (эллипсис, так сказать)?

Comment: >Частица в форме сказуемого - это круто. А не перебор ли?

Ну да. А кто мне запретит? Только не в *форме*, а в *роли*.  
Это разговорная речь, здесь и не такое может быть.  
Тут сокровенный смысл в том, что в данном контексте "что" (чем бы оно там не являлась) _**однородно**_ с последующим сымсловым сказуемым. В отличие, скажем, от "Им что [стоит] сделать то-то и то-то", где запятой быть не может, хотя там та же частица только в другой роли.

Comment: Свою ошибку я заметила, но поленилась исправить. Думала, поправят меня или нет :)) Шучу.   

> ..."что" (чем бы оно там ни являлось)... >  
В том-то и дело: это *что* - не*что* загадочное, во всяком случае для меня. Частицы, как правило, не отделяются запятыми, в отличие от междометий, к примеру. Но ни междометием, ни местоимением "оно" быть не может. Ну да ладно, черт с ним, пусть будет частицей с запятой. Но не сказуемым (имхо).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, здесь может быть или запятая, или (с интонацией подчеркивания)тире

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой же вопрос, как задала [@karin](/users/59/karin). Как обосновать тире, кроме интонации, и какая здесь грамматическая основа?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, знак здесь не нужен. Во всяком случае не обязателен. *Что*=*разве*.

Comment: Тогда чем является слово "что"?

Comment: Слово "что" - усилительная частица

Comment: Прочитайте вслух обе фразы: "Он разве не верит?" и "Он что() не верит?". Во втором предложении без паузы никак нельзя. Знак должен быть.

Comment: Тогда какой?

Comment: Что - это частица, но вопросительная. Она отделяется запятой.  
"Что" не равно "разве". "Разве" = "неужели" выражает сомнение, "что" = "верно" - скорее предположение.  
К тому же отнесение "разве к частицам" сомнительно. Ушакоы, например в подобных контекстах считает "разве" наречием. Правда в те времена теория частиц только разрабатывалась.